# Hibernate moving from JTA eager to lazy loading and session per thread

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading, jta, thread-local

I am using in hibernate conf:

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

And :

```
private static final ThreadLocal<Session> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<Session>();
```

Doing after example:

http://hibernateannotation.blogspot.com/2012/03/hibernate-singleton-sessionfactory.html

I am trying to move from JTA to Thread based sessions.

My problem is that, in every example, after items are queried lazily, they are commmiting the transaction and closing session:

http://www.laliluna.de/download/first-hibernate-2-example-tutorial-en.pdf

So why I wanted to move from `JTA` to `Thread`, was that I need my session to be open, until my `thread` closes. Because when they close `session` after lazily loading objects, and I try to get object attributes, I get `lazyloading error`.

**Is there a way to accomplish this, so that session is managed by thread**, I know smthin similar is in `Spring`, but I am just doing plain hibernate in my webapp.